# Uniformize date formats - how to?

Tags: php, mysql, feed, date-sorting

I have two sources of information and those sources have dates in different formats.

**Source A**
*Wed, 17 Nov 2010 12:14:10 +0000* (from a rss feed)

**Source B**
*YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS* (from mysql datetime)

Request:
**I would like to order them by date to retrieve only the last occurrences.**

But, and to put it even more difficult, those that are stored into the database should have in consideration the TIME. Because several records could be created on the same day.

I have control over the mysql output format to choose from.
I don't have any control about the output coming from the rss feed.

This doesn't seem to be an easy achievement, and I'm wondering:

What could you suggest here?

**Update:** 
I was thinking about: 
Working source A like this:
a) creating an array for months and the specific month number
b) Retrive two chars after the first comma (or three if we count the space) (the day)
c) Convert "Nov" to a number (by using the array previously created);
d) Retrieve the 2010 (not sure how);
e) Place the year on the left, add a - place the month, and a -, place the day, add 00:00:00

At this time, they both will be equal and that could help...
But, I feel really dummy about doing all this... :s Isn't there a smart way? :)

Over - php(zend) / mysql

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use PHP 5.3, I would use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to normalize the date formats into a  common format.

For mySQL dates:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2010-11-17');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

For the RFC 2822 format, this *should* work (never tested it yet):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('r', 'Wed, 17 Nov 2010 12:14:10 +0000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I think `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date))` will work just as well, <5.3.

Comment: @deceze I wasn't entirely sure about the `r` format but come to think of it, `strtotime()` can probably deal with it as well, true

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that we have such thing as ISO format. I will give it a try and post back the results. Thanks a lot. :) (@all ps- you can see my update for amusement :s );

Comment: @MEM yeah. ISO isn't entirely correct, the `Wed, 17 Nov 2010....` date format is specified in RFC 2822. Corrected

Comment: Just one question: That static call seems really nice. And It needs no dependences. It feels like php is a OOP language, not only because I can create my own classes, but because php has their own that we can use. I'm wondering if: a) No one will slap me with that static call right? b) where can we see other OOP functionalities like those?

Comment: @MEM the static call is fine in this case, it returns a `DateTime` object (the manual examples do it the same way). It's a bit of an exception, it would be more fitting to use a normal constructor for this but `createFromFormat` came later as an addition to the library. b) I can't think of an example right now but I'm sure there are some

Comment: @Pekka - about the RFC - 2822 (thanks for that addon!) I will look more into it. I know nothing about RFC.

Comment: @Pekka - Do you believe that those classes will be more and more common with the advance of php ?

Comment: @MEM yup, I'm pretty sure `DateTime` is the future: It's object oriented, it's clean, and it can store *any* date (even before 1900) so it doesn't suffer from the [Year 2038 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) as ordinary timestamps do

Comment: I buy the oop has a future proof. That's enough. About the bug... I will say nothing. I was here when the Bug of year 2000 fiasco came out. ;) Oh well... I will skeptically read it however. ;) Thanks a lot for your additional comments. I will put the code to test. I'm curious about that Web, 12 ... transformation. :)

Comment: @Pekka, @deceze - I'm on PHP 5.2.14 . No luck for me. :( Will the deceze solution work on this case, by having on $date the RFC 2822 format?

Comment: @MEM yes, it should! Try it out.

Comment: Just done it. Nice. Shame however that I can't use PHP 5.3 new features.

Comment: @MEM too bad! But 5.3 will come to your server sooner or later.